# Чистая математика. Разработать формулу графика

Tags: график, линейная-алгебра

Есть некая последовательность значений графика.
Первое значение 0, при каждой следующей (целочисленной) итерации текущее значение умножается на B и прибавляется A.
В итоге, нужно иметь возможность получить значение графика в любой, даже НЕцелочисленной точке.

```
A
AB+A
(AB+A)*B+A
((AB+A)*B+A)*B+A
(((AB+A)*B+A)*B+A)*B+A
```

Раскрыл скобки. Называется, упростил выражение, но проще не стало )

```
A
AB+A
(AB+A)*B+A              AB^2+AB+A
(AB^2+AB+A)*B+A         AB^3+AB^2+AB+A
(AB^3+AB^2+AB+A)*B+A    AB^4+AB^3+AB^2+AB+A
```

Алгебру учил ещё в прошлом тысячелетии, ничего не помню.
Посоветуйте, какими интрегалами пользоваться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

n-й член последовательности (считая `А` первым)

```
 AB^(n-1)+AB^(n-2)+..AB^2+AB+A
```

А за скобки

```
 A(B^(n-1)+B^(n-2)+..B^2+B+1)
```

По формуле суммы геометрической прогрессии всё сильно упрощается:

```
 A* (B^n-1)/(B-1)
```